# Integration results in unhandled Promise rejection

Tags: angular, intro.js

I want to integrate intro.js in my app.

I get intro.js framework (2.4.0) and @types (2.0.28).
My code build, but don't execute.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my',
    template: require('./my.component.html')
})
export class My implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {
        introJs('introduction').start();
    }
}
```

introJS method's are recognize in TypeScript.
[image]

I have this error :

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: introJs is not defined ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: ReferenceError: introJs is not defined(…) ReferenceError: introJs is not defined
```

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: You need to install & refer typings for `IntroJS`

Comment: You are importing the library?

Comment: Yes, I install @type/intro.js and importing the library intro.js. My environment recognize introJS methods

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly use JS directly with angular2 . You can follow [this tutorial](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/01/include-external-javascript-libraries-in-an-angular-2-typescript-project/) or [this package](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-intro) for the right solution . Best of luck.